# JQGrid: multiselect filter flashing before data loads

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I have a JQGrid which have a multiselect filter. Once I hit Search the grid works fine. But a small issue which my client doesn't like. The issue is the multiselect drop down (the one which is in header filter) does not load completely until the data loads completely. That means I see flash of unstyled content for few seconds. Here is a screenshot. Any idea how to resolve this.

FYI: I am using all same libraries as it is used [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithSearchingToolbarMultilpe1__48.htm)

[image]

Comment: The demo which you reference uses very old code, created for version 4.8. One can use current possibilities existing in free jqGrid to remove the most `setTimeout` calls, which are origin of the problem. Moreover free jqGrid supports now `"in"` operation, which could be very good used in multiselect filter. I can post you details later.

Comment: @Oleg: Thanks Oleg. I am still looking how/where to remove setTimeout.

Comment: I mean mostly that one should initialize multiselect (call `$elem.multiselect(options);`) inside of `selectFilled` callback instead of `dataInit` callback. The `selectFilled` callback will be called **after** the `select` is filled. Thus one don't need to use `setTimeout` inside of `dataInitMultiselect`. The method `modifySearchingFilter` is not needed at all. Look http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/dj35p611/9/ created for https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/254, but one should make additional modifications for your case.